# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning React, and playing with the clock example. The app was created with `create-react-app . --template typescript`.

I modified `App.tsx` as follow:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Clock from './Clock';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Clock />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my `Clock.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Clock extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }</div>
    }
}

export default Clock;

// My take on tick
function tick(parent: React.Component) {
    const el = <div>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>;
    ReactDOM.render(el, parent);
}
```

However, it does not compile:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>[]'.
      Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2769

    14 | function tick(parent: React.Component) {
    15 |     const el = <div>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>;
  > 16 |     ReactDOM.render(el, parent);
       |                     ^
```

I thought it was a problem compiling `JSX.Element` to `ReactElement`. Other answers indicate that this should works fine. I remove the function out and modify the `index.tsx` to

```js
const el = <div>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>;
ReactDOM.render(el, document.getElementById('root'));
```

then it does compile just fine.

How can I fix my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your `parent`. It's type should be `HTMLElement` which can get by `document.getElementById('root')`, not `JSX.Element` or `React.Component`

If you trying example:

```js
function tick(parent: HTMLElement | null) {
  const el = <div>{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }</div>;
  ReactDOM.render(el, parent);}

setInterval(() => {
  tick(document.getElementById('root'))
}, 1000);
```

Your needn't clock in this case.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out this morning after reading [React Components, Elements, and Instances](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).